# How do I Copy an Android Project to Make a Pro Version?

Tags: android

I want to make a pro version of my app that is ad free and contains more features. I have tried copying the project and changing the class name and such but it doesn't want to run. So what I was wondering is if there is an easy way to archive this or do I have to go through it all and copy and paste each file and change paths and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT many years later: that's what build flavors are for.

---

The best way is via a library. Stuff all your common code into an Android library project, create two apps - free and pro, make them both reference the library. You can even put some resources into a library.

You can even have whole activities in the library. Just make sure the manifest lists the activity class name correctly, in case Java package name differs between the app and the library.

As for project copying, you probably forgot to change the manifest accordingly.

Comment: Every `<activity>` element has `android:name` in it. By default, it lists the activity class' name, under assumption that the Android package name (the one under `<manifest package="...">`) is the same as the Java package name, which the the first line in every Java source. In the copying scenario, those two may not match. So you need to change the `android:name` to the full class name, including the Java package name. Same goes for services, receivers and the app class (if any).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to use the option "Create from existing source" in the Eclipse's new project